# Run two python functions simultaneously with sleep

Tags: python, function, sleep

I have two functions but I can't get them to run all the time with the `foo()` function that sleeps for some time.

```
import time

filename = "test.dat"

def foo():
    print "It deletes dat file and creates a new one"
    time.sleep(xxx)

def bar():
    print "Writes to dat file"

while True:
    foo()
    bar()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:
`filename` is defined as a `global variable` and as soon as `foo()` deletes that file and creates a new one, `filename` becomes a  `local variable`, so `bar()` function can't find `dat` file and that's why it does not run at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I correctly understood the problem, but try this one and let me know if that is what you want

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo(x):
    while True:
        print ("It deletes dat file and creates new one")
        time.sleep(x)

def bar():
    while True:
        print ("Wtires to dat file")

process1 = Process(target=foo, args=(0.05,))
process2 = Process(target=bar)
process1.start()
process2.start()
```

with this code `foo()` will run with `x = 0.05` seconds break and `bar()` will run all the time... but note that "all the time" means veeeeery often and with no breaks:)

Comment: I'm getting this error: |Invalid Syntax" and it has marked p1.

p1.start()

Comment: can you show full log? There is no `p1. p1.start()` string in my code

Comment: You had a syntax error:
process1 = Process(target=foo, args=(0.05,)
instead of:
process1 = Process(target=foo, args=(0.05)) 
But anyway foo() function does not run at all.

Comment: oh... yeap, I missed one bracket. correct is `process1 = Process(target=foo, args=(0.05,))` you should use comma in `args` as `args=(5)` is a `int` type variable, `args=(5,)` is `tuple` type variable

Comment: So, i figured where the problem is. The problem is with the `dat` file. It seems that it can't be used by both functions at the same time. Any idea on how to work around it?

Comment: hm... if this file contain only text data, you can copy it to another temporary file... but I'm sure that there are more convenient ways to make it.... `shelve` or something else